# Can I make this work in php if ($_POST["answer"] == """)

Tags: php, post, quotes

I want to be able to read quotes as quotes in my input field so how do I make this work in php:

```
if ($_POST["answer"] == """ )
```

right now all I get is a parse error

Comment: Read up on the basics of strings and how to use quotes. Quick fix, use `$_POST["answer"] == '"'`

Comment: if ($_POST["answer"] == '""'

Comment: If you are lazy to learn, answer is to escape them `\"`

Comment: neith '"' or "\"" will read a " entered into the post field

Comment: @user3555228 take a look at your character encoding.

Comment: @ Thiago Franca How do you do that? Thanks again

Comment: @user3555228 try with `mb_convert_encoding($yourstring, $toEncode, $fromEncode);`, learn about [supported characters encode on php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php).
look: 

    `mb_convert_encoding($_POST['answer'], 'UTF-8', 'auto');`

Comment: @ Thiago Franca Your help is much appreciated, thanks!  I figured it out by combining your answers, this worked: if ($_POST["answer"] == '\"' )

Comment: this is very strange, because if you do a var_dump ('\"'), you will see as a result \", is not escaping ", so the only way is in $ _POST ['answer'] you be getting \", may be that the apache or php is escaping this character.

Comment: @Mr. Alien you are wrong

Comment: @WesleyMurch you are wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
if ($_POST["answer"] == '"')
```

or

```
if ($_POST["answer"] == "\"")
```

maybe apache or php escaping " from $_POST, then use

```
if ($_POST["answer"] == '\"')
```

Comment: does not work thanks anyhoo

Comment: if ($_POST["answer"] == '\"' )

Comment: @user3555228 added to the answer, i appreciate if you make a answer as correct!

Answer (score 0):

You can either wrapping `"` around `' '`:

```
if ($_POST["answer"] == '"'
```

or escape it using:

```
if ($_POST["answer"] == "\"")
```

Comment: neither works thanks though

Comment: this will do it:  if ($_POST["answer"] == '\"' )